# Why does every site makes me acknowledge cookie usage?

Tags: cookies, legal, user-education

In the last year or so every other site on the net started showing different kinds of notification that they're using cookies and I should be aware of it. The sheer number of different sites doing this made me abandon the initial good-will-idea and rather think that there has been some kind of legislation forcing sites to show that notice, especially since until recently, it's been a trend on US-based sites. Now I'm seeing this also on german sites (I think I would have noticed an appropriate legislation), so I wonder -- what's the background for this overreaching user information? Why this intensity all of a sudden?

Comment: Every such notification I've seen has a link explaining why the website has notified you and what they use the cookies for.  I believe, though this is just off the top of my head, that it's to do with EU privacy laws and the lack of informed consent in the old model of storing/tracking cookies without telling the user.

Comment: @ChrisMurray is right, the EU has more stricter laws on companies/websites informing people about what they do with their info, because they care for the privacy of their peoplea bit more than the US, i.e., the Netherlands, where i live, is even more extreme in it, by forcing the bigger website to not function, untill the user either accepts or doesn't accept (which can be irrelevant since the "cookie law" has been changed not more then 5 days ago).

Comment: It is also likely to combat against more and more users using Ghostery (or other cookie managers) to only allow the necessary cookies. There are a lot of gray lines between 'allow cookies' and 'block cookies'. Some cookies are useful to you while some are only useful for people making money off of you. Their hope is that if they say, "we use cookies", you may be like, "ok, have at it" rather than taking the time to only allow necessary cookies.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is indeed an EU legislation : European Union Directive 2009/136/EC says that websites must get consent from their visitors about information they intend to keep/store/retrieve on their computer/device.

There is even a fine, up to £500,000 for those who don't comply.

Source :

- [ICO (Information Commissione's Office) Blog](http://ico.org.uk/news/blog/2012/updated-ico-advice-guidance-e-privacy-directive-eu-cookie-law)
- European Comission '[Information Providers Guide](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm)'
- [Huffingtonpost](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2012/05/26/internet-cookies-new-law-_n_1547450.html)
- [Cookielaw.org](http://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/) :)

**[Edit]** [A more complete answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/454757/why-are-websites-suddenly-asking-me-about-cookies)

Comment: This is a good answer. To add to it, the law isn't particularly clear on whether warning on cookie usage is required, so companies do it in case.

Comment: AFAIK the law isn't clear on whether these warnings about cookie usage go *far enough* - its wording implies you need to get consent *before* using any cookies, rather than just informing the user when you're using cookies.  That sites have instead adopted these cookie warnings seems to be a compromise that goes towards implementing the regulation but stops short of fully doing so, because that would impact usability/user annoyance far too much.

Comment: I had to update a few websites to comply with this law... in the end we followed suit with the larger sites which were effectively just having a privacy / cookies page which says "we use cookies, if you don't want them go away". there was much consternation... why re-implement cookie black / whitelisting on millions of websites when browsers have it built in? </rant>

Comment: Sidenote : [here](https://github.com/r4vi/block-the-eu-cookie-shit-list)'s a solution to get rid of these warnings once and for all (add that list to your ad blocker).